# Eigenvalues of Schrodinger equation in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: partial-differential-equations, bessel-functions, eigenfunctions, cylindrical-coordinates

I have Schrodinger equation of the form:
$$ \left[\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{r}^{2}}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^{}}{\partial{r}^{}}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\left(\frac{\partial^{}}{\partial{\varphi}^{}}+i\alpha r^{2}\right)^2+ \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{z}^{2}}\right] \Psi = -\lambda^{2}\Psi $$

where the Boundary conditions are:

$\Psi(r,\varphi,z) = 0 \ni  \  r\geq r_{0}$ and $z \in (-\infty,-z_{0}] \ \cup \ [z_{0},\infty)  \  $ i.e. $\Psi = 0 $ on the surface of a cylinder of radius $r_{0}$ and height $2z_{0}$.

$\Psi(r,\varphi+2\pi,z)=\Psi(r,\varphi,z) \ \forall \ \varphi \in [0,2\pi)$

Is there a general method to solve for the eigenvalues and eigenfunctions of such an PDE with Dirichlet BCs ?

I have tried to reduce the problem into a single variable by considering $\Psi$ to be separable and then performing a Fourier transform for the functions in $\varphi,z$.

This gives me the following differential equation:
$$ \left[\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial{r}^{2}}+\frac{1}{r} \frac{\partial^{}}{\partial{r}^{}}+\frac{1}{r^{2}}\left({k_{\varphi}}+i\alpha r^{2}\right)^2+ k_{z}^{2}\right] R(r) = -\lambda^{2} R(r) $$
In this case the problem takes a form much similar to the Bessel equation. Can it be further modified to be transformed into the general Bessel equation to find the eigenvalues and eigen functions.

Comment: You seem to have been too eager to remove the $\varphi$-dependence from your final equation. The $\varphi$ and $r$ degrees of freedom don't seem to be separable, see the inconvenient $r$-dependent term denoted by red arrow [in this screenshot from Wolfram Mathematica](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tzfO.png).

Comment: Yes, the idea to FT was to try and decouple r, $\varphi$.